# How to solve Probability problems of this kind?

Tags: probability

Out of 100 students, two sections of 40 and 60 students are formed. If you and your friend are among 100 students, what is the probability that:

1. You both enter the same section.
2. You both enter different sections.

Please make your answer as descriptive as you can. I've medium knowledge on the subject of probability, and this is a question from Grade 11. Thank you very much!

Comment: In how many ways can you pick $40$ students to be grouped in the smaller group out of the $100$ students total?  In how many ways can you and your friend be among the $40$ for the smaller group?  In how many ways can you and your friend be among the $60$ for the larger group?  Recognizing that each way of grouping the students is equally likely, make a conclusion.

Comment: Probability fens (trees) are another option. The first level is "you go into A/B" and the second is "your friend goes into A/B". Now just multiply and add probabilities.

Comment: @JMoravitz, thanks for your response. :) 40 students can be selected in $^{100}C_{40} $ ways. My friend and I can be in the same group among 40 students in 1 ways... right? I guess so because, there are only two cases -   we are among those 40 students or not. If we are, then there's only 1 case i.e both in the same group of 40. $^{100}C_{40} = large calculation$ And a similar number for group of 60. I am sorry, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel, thanks for your response. :) I've learned about selecting m objects out of n objects. But not dividing n objects in m groups. So, can't help. P(Me getting selected in group of 40) =  40/100. Similarly for my friend, P(friend in group of 40) = 2/5. Product of these two =4/25. For 2nd group P(me in 2nd group) = 3/5. P(friend in 2nd group) = 3/5. Product = 9/25. Sum of probabilities  = 13/25. Answer given is 17/33. :(

Comment: @Aditya You may **only** multiply probabilities like that if the events are independent.  In general $Pr(E\cap F)\neq Pr(E)\cdot Pr(F)$.  For my suggestion, you will arrive at an answer of $\frac{\binom{100}{38}+\binom{100}{58}}{\binom{100}{40}}$.  If you go through the effort of replacing with factorial notation, you will have very nice cancellations.  For Parcly's suggestion, yes, $Pr(\text{me in the 40})=Pr(\text{friend in the 40})=\frac{40}{100}$ it is **not** true that $Pr(\text{both of us in the 40})=\frac{4}{25}$

Comment: Instead, $Pr(\text{both of us in the 40})=Pr(\text{me in 40})\cdot Pr(\text{friend in 40} \textbf{GIVEN THAT} \text{me in 40}) = \frac{40}{100}\cdot \frac{39}{99}$.  Both methods arrive at the same answer overall.

Comment: @JMoravitz, thank you for helping me out. I got the answer! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be the section you are assigned, $Y$ that of your friend, with values $\{A,B\}$.

You are in the same section if $X=Y$

$$\mathsf P(X{=}Y) ~=~ \mathsf P(X{=}A)\,\mathsf P(Y{=}A\mid X{=}A)+\mathsf P(X{=}B)\,\mathsf P(Y{=}B\mid X{=}B)$$

You are in different sections if the complement happens.

$$\mathsf P(X{\neq}Y) ~=~ \mathsf P(X{=}A)\,\mathsf P(Y{=}B\mid X{=}A)+\mathsf P(X{=}B)\,\mathsf P(Y{=}A\mid X{=}B)$$

Of course, as $\mathsf P(X{=}Y)=1-\mathsf P(X{\neq}Y)$, calculating one yields the other.

---

Can you find the six factors without any trouble?

$\mathsf P(X{=}A)$ the probability that you are in the section of 40 students.

$\mathsf P(Y{=}A\mid X{=}A)$ the probability that your friend is in the section of 40 students, when given that you are too.

Et cetera.

Comment: Thanks for answering it! I'm sorry, I can't proceed with what clues you gave to me. (limited knowledge and learning). I think, I can calculate $P(X=A) = 40/100 = 2/5$ Right? I can't calculate the terms like  $P(Y=A∣X=A)$ Sorry.

Comment: @Aditya By the same principle, it is $39/99$ .  When given that you are in section A, there are 39 of the 99 remaining seats/places your friend could be in section A also.  Hence the probability that you are both in section A is thus: $\tfrac{40}{100}\tfrac{39}{99}$.  Likewise the probability you are both in section B is: ...

Comment: I got the answer. $\frac{17}{33}$. Thank you! :)